# to know the package jar used in tomcat at runtime

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have servlet-api.jar in tomcat/lib folder and WEB-INF/lib/servlet-api 3.1.0 jar (i.e application dependent). I would like to know how to find which version of jar is currently in use when tomcat is running.
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html from here, i see order of class loading is as follows

```
Bootstrap classes of your JVM
/WEB-INF/classes of your web application
/WEB-INF/lib/*.jar of your web application
System class loader classes (described above)
Common class loader classes (described above)
```

but how to know if common class loader overrides the above jar present in WEB-INF/lib folder.
can someone please answer.

Comment: This is answered on the page linked in the question: “the web application class loader will always delegate first for JavaEE API classes for the specifications implemented by Tomcat (Servlet, JSP, EL, WebSocket)”

Comment: And since that sentence can be hard to parse: Yes, that means it'll use the jar from `tomcat/lib` before anything from `WEB-INF`

Comment: if i want to test if tomcat/lib servlet-api.jar is jar picked at runtime, can you please suggest how to test it. thanks

Comment: Two suggestions: set verbose classloading on the container. Examine file handles with tools appropriate for your OS